# How can I get all index name from Elasticsearch by using golang client library?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I am using this library in go https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/esapi#CatIndicesRequest to query from Elasticsearch.

I has some examples on querying but I am looking for a API method to get all index from Elasticsearch cluster. But I can't find one I can use from their doc. Does anyone know what the best way to get all index? like the http api `_cat/indices`

Comment: It's not clear what `/_cat/indices` doesn't provide that you would need.

Comment: I mean how to get it via the go lang library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7/esapi"
)

func main() {

    cfg := elasticsearch.Config{
        Addresses: []string{
            "http://localhost:9243",
        },
        Username: "foo",
        Password: "bar",
    }
    es, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    res, err := esapi.CatIndicesRequest{Format: "json"}.Do(context.Background(), es)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(res.String())
}
```

You can tweak the `CatIndicesRequest` to format the output for your case.
For example, if you use `CatIndicesRequest{Pretty: true, Human: true}`. It will return something like this:

```
[200 OK] green open .ent-search-actastic-workplace_search_accounts_v16                                                                           yvaDvj9RTMOoWqIpKdC_kw 1 1       1      0  12.1kb     6kb
green open .ent-search-workplace-search-content-events-ecs-ilm-logs-production-2022.01.23-000003                                        1D1BagTFQ6ypoZh2RdoUhQ 1 1       0      0    416b    208b
green open .ent-search-actastic-workplace_search_search_groups_v4-name-unique-constraint                                                b_FRbLWJQfqXXxyTdcU2cQ 1 1       1      0     7kb   3.5kb
green open .ent-search-actastic-crawler_crawl_requests_v4                                                                               kaUWb7YlTEeFH-Gcpz50qA 1 1       0      0    416b    208b
green open .ent-search-api-ecs-ilm-logs-production-2022.03.09-000016                                                                    EKZZOtqOR_e8pOztXsLU1g 1 1       0      0    416b    208b
```